# arcsin of multiples

Tags: trigonometry

I know there is an identity for $\sin(nx)$, I wonder if there also is one for $\arcsin(nx)$ without having to resort to the infinite series?

Thank you all

Comment: No, there is no simple formula for $\arcsin(2x)$ in terms of $\arcsin(x)$.  Also note: the domain of $\arcsin(2x)$ is not the same as the domain of $\arcsin(x)$.